# Dask list index out of range reading JSON files from S3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask, python-s3fs

I'm trying to read a bunch of JSON files stored on S3, but is raising a `list index out of range` when I compute the DataFrame

My call to open the JSON files is like this:

```
pets_data = dd.read_json("s3://my-bucket/pets/*.json", meta=meta, blocksize=None, orient="records", lines=False)
```

and Is failing when I call `to_csv` (to S3 or to local, both fails)

```
# save on local fails
pets_data.to_csv(
        "pets-full-data.csv",
        single_file=True,
        index=False
    )
# save on S3 fails as well
pets_data.to_csv(
        "s3://my-bucket/pets-full-data.csv",
        single_file=True,
        index=False
    )
```

StackTrace:

```
File "main.py", line 89, in <module>
pets_data.to_csv(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 1423, in to_csv
return to_csv(self, filename, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 808, in to_csv
value = to_csv_chunk(dfs[0], first_file, **kwargs)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**NOTE:** This only occurs when I attempt to open the files from S3, when I open the files from local storage everything goes well

Comment: Please check what files you see on s3: `import s3fs; s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(); s3.glob("s3://my-bucket/pets/*.json")`

Comment: Your answer gave me a key point it fails when I try to list the files, the problem was that I forgot to add ListBucket permission
Although I'm wondering why the library fails (in appearance) at compute time, instead of raise a error due S3 permissions

Comment: Since you provide `meta`, dask doesn't need to read any data until compute time, but it probably should have noticed that there were zero files beforehand.